# $c$-coarsely connected space for every $c>0$

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, terminology

A metric space $(X,d)$ is called $c$-*coarsely connected* if for every two points $x,y\in X$ there exists a sequence $x=x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n=y$ of points in $X$ such that $d(x_{i-1},x_i)\leq c$.

**Question:** 
Is there an established terminology for spaces which are $c$-coarsely connected for every $c>0$?

**Examples:** connected spaces, $\mathbf Q$ with the standard metric induced from $\mathbf R$, $\mathbf Z$ with the metric induced from the circle via an injective homomorphism.

I am thinking of calling it *finely connected*.

Comment: What you call c-coarsely connected is usually called c-chainable.

Comment: It is almost the same as "the space has connected completion".

Comment: It seems that existence of $c$-chain for any $c>0$ defines a coarse structure (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarse_structure), why not to use it?

Comment: Such a space is called chainable.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Misha, thanks for the answer!

Comment: If $X$ is c-coarsely connected for *some* c then it is coarsely connected. For example all finitely generated groups are coarsely connected.

Comment: I like the terminology "coarsely connected" because it's a coarse property, and also because it is equivalent to be coarsely equivalent to a connected metric space.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin almost in which sense? Having connected completion sounds much stronger. I think it's not hard to produce complete metric space that are not connected (totally disconnected) that are $c$-coarsely connected for every $c$. Also we could arrange that there are points $x,y$, such that the smallest radius $R_c$ of a ball centered at $x$ in which there is a $c$-path joining $x$ to $y$, tends to infinity when $c\to 0$ (if the completion is connected, clearly $\sup_c R_c<\infty$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the term *chainable* is sometimes used for such spaces, it clashes with the established usage of "chainable" in continuum theory (e.g., 
[Each homogeneous nondegenerate chainable continuum is a pseudo-arc](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1959-010-03/S0002-9939-1959-0105072-6/) by R. H. Bing).

The term *chain connected* is used in papers on discrete homotopies (e.g., [Essential circles and Gromov-Hausdorff convergence of covers](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.0808.pdf) by Plaut and Wilkins) and [in a few textbooks](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22chain+connected%22+metric+space) such as [Introduction to General Topology](https://books.google.com/books/about/Introduction_to_General_Topology.html?id=fvCpXrube5wC) by Joshi:

[image]

Incidentally, item (b) demonstrates the difference between  being chain connected and having connected completion.